# Joining two Python Dictionaries on key

Tags: python, dictionary, ordereddictionary, defaultdict

Have two Dictionaries in Python and would like to make a join using a key.

The first dictionary "d" is OrderedDict like this:

```
[OrderedDict([
          ('id', '1'),
          ('date', '20170101'),
OrderedDict([
          ('id', '2'),
          ('date', '20170102'),
OrderedDict([
          ('id', '3'),
          ('date', '20170102')]
```

The second one "dd" is defaultdict and it's like this:

```
defaultdict(int, {'1': 14, '2': 5, '3': 7})
```

I want to make a join using possibilities of "operator" library and using keys but the approach is not working for me because I dont know exactly how should I treat the keys in defaultdict:

```
sort_key = operator.itemgetter("id")

ks=[ k for k in dd.keys()]

for i, j in zip(sorted(d, key=sort_key), sorted(dd,key=ks)):
    i.update(j)
```

How should I correctly perform the joining?

Desirable output will be OrderedDict with additional values from the second dictionary:

```
[OrderedDict([
          ('id', '1'),
          ('date', '20170101'),
          ('quantity', '14'),
OrderedDict([
          ('id', '2'),
          ('date', '20170102'),
          ('quantity', '5'),
OrderedDict([
          ('id', '3'),
          ('date', '20170102'),
          ('quantity', '7')]
```

Thanks!

Comment: What do expect them to look like after the join? You will get more and better answers if you create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example.  Especially make sure that the input and expected test data are complete (not pseudo-data), and can be easily cut and and paste into an editor to allow testing proposed solutions.

Comment: You probably sohuld use a better data format. If `id`s are unique, put the OrderedDicts in a dict.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```
from collections import OrderedDict, defaultdict
d = [OrderedDict([
      ('id', '1'),
      ('date', '20170101')]),
    OrderedDict([
      ('id', '2'),
      ('date', '20170102')]),
    OrderedDict([
      ('id', '3'),
      ('date', '20170102')])]

marker = defaultdict(int, {'1': 14, '2': 5, '3': 7})
new_d = [OrderedDict([(a, b) for a, b in i.items()]+[('quantity', marker[i['id']])]) for i in d]
```

Output:

```
[OrderedDict([('id', '1'), ('date', '20170101'), ('quantity', 14)]),
OrderedDict([('id', '2'), ('date', '20170102'), ('quantity', 5)]),
OrderedDict([('id', '3'), ('date', '20170102'), ('quantity', 7)])]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
from collections import OrderedDict, defaultdict


d = [OrderedDict([
          ('id', '1'),
          ('date', '20170101')]),
OrderedDict([
          ('id', '2'),
          ('date', '20170102')]),
OrderedDict([
          ('id', '3'),
          ('date', '20170102')]) ]

dd = defaultdict(int, {'1': 14, '2': 5, '3': 7})
id1 = set([ di['id'] for di in d])
id2 = set( dd.keys() )
final_keys = id1 & id2
to_be_del = []
for di in d:
    id = di['id']
    if id not in final_keys:
        to_be_del.append(di)
        continue
    q = dd[id]
    di['quantity'] = q
for di in to_be_del:
    d.remove(di)

print(d)
```

1. Get list of ids from OrderedDict list
2. Get list of keys from dd
3. Get intersection of these keys
4. Set the quantity from dd and delete OrderedDict if it's id is missing in the defaultdict.

https://ideone.com/ZXVcQu